# Moving surface within smaller surface doesn't show previously hidden components

Tags: python, pygame

I'm coding some custom GUI objects for usage in pygame menus, while coding a scrollable box I hit an error.

This box works by moving a  surface (which contains the components which are moved when scrolling) within a smaller surface which acts like a window to the confined surface. The surfaces mostly display correctly: the contents of the inner surface which are visible initially (the parts which fit within the window surface) display correctly, but when the inner surface is moved to reveal previously hidden components they are not displayed, the initial visible move correctly and are displayed when they return.

I think the issue is with the outer surface's clipping area thinking that only the already revealed components should be displayed and that the others are still hidden but I don't know.

The custom GUI components always have a Rect (returns the bounding rect for that component) and Draw (blits the component to the screen) functions.
Here is the code for the scroll area (and it's parent class):

```
class ScrollArea(BaseComponent):
"Implements a section of screen which is operable by scroll wheel"
def __init__(self,surface,rect,colour,components):
    """surface is what this is drawn on
    rect is location + size
    colour is colour of screen
    components is iterable of components to scroll through (they need Draw and Rect functions), this changes the objects location and surface
    """
    super().__init__(surface)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    self.colour = colour
    self.components = components
    self.Make()

def HandleEvent(self, event):
    "Pass events to this; it enables the area to react to them"
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and self._scroll_rect.h > self.rect.h:
        if event.button == 4: self.scroll_y = min(self.scroll_y + 15,self._scroll_y_min)
        if event.button == 5: self.scroll_y = max(self.scroll_y - 15,self._scroll_y_max)

def Make(self):
    "Updates the area, activates any changes made"
    _pos = self.rect.topleft
    self._sub_surface = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size,pygame.SRCALPHA)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(_pos,self._sub_surface.get_rect().size)
    self._sub_surface.unlock()#hopefully fixes issues

    self._scroll_surf = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)
    self._scroll_rect = self._scroll_surf.get_rect()
    scroll_height = 5
    for component in self.components:
        component.surface = self._scroll_surf
        component.Rect().y = scroll_height
        component.Rect().x = 5
        component.Draw()
        scroll_height += component.Rect().h + 5
    self._scroll_rect.h = max(self.rect.h,scroll_height)
    self.scroll_y = 0
    self._scroll_y_min = 0
    self._scroll_y_max = -(self._scroll_rect.h - self.rect.h)

def Draw(self):
    "Draw the area and its inner components"
    self._sub_surface.fill((255, 255, 255, 0))
    self._sub_surface.blit(self._scroll_surf,(0,self.scroll_y))
    pygame.draw.rect(self._sub_surface,self.colour,((0,0),self.rect.size),2)
    self.surface.blit(self._sub_surface,self.rect.topleft)

def Rect(self):
    "Return the rect of this component"
    return self.rect

class BaseComponent:
    def __init__(self,surface):
        "surface is what this is drawn on"
        self.surface = surface
    def HandleEvent(self,event):
        "Pass events into this for the component to react ot them"
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def Make(self):
        "Redo calculations on how component looks"
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def Draw(self):
        "Draw component"
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def ReDraw(self):
        "Call Make then draw functions of component"
        self.Make()
        self.Draw()
    def Rect(self):
        "Return the rect of this component"
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

To test this I used this code and a label component:

```
screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480
font_label = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",22)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
grey = (125,125,125)
def LoadLoop():
    #objects
    scroll_components = []
    for i in range(20):
        scroll_components.append(Components.Label(screen,(0,0),str(i),font_label,grey))
    scroll_area = Components.ScrollArea(screen,Components.CenterRect(screen_width/2,3*screen_height/16 + 120,300,200),grey,scroll_components)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    #events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        scroll_area.HandleEvent(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    #graphics        
    screen.fill(black)
    scroll_area.Draw(components)
    #render
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

This is the label component's code (it basically just prints text to screen with the location given as it's center):

```
class Label(BaseComponent):
    "Class which implements placing text on a screen"
    def __init__(self,surface,center,text,font,text_colour):
        """surface is what this is drawn on
        center is the coordinates of where the text is to be located
        text is the text of the label
        font is the font of the label
        text_colour is the text's colour
        """
        super().__init__(surface)
        self.center = center
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.text_colour = text_colour
        self.Make()
    def HandleEvent(self,event):
        "Labels have no events they react to,\nso this does nothing"

    def Make(self):
        "(Re)creates the label which is drawn,\nthis must be used if any changes to the label are to be carried out"
        self._text_surf = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.text_colour)
        self._text_rect = self._text_surf.get_rect()
        self._text_rect.center = self.center

    def Draw(self):
        "Draw the label , will not react to any changes made to the label"
        self.surface.blit(self._text_surf,self._text_rect)
    def Rect(self):
        "Return the rect of this component"
        return self._text_rect
```

This is the window produced by this code:
[Before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46BRT.png)
[After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn10Z.png)

I also did it with a different size of ScrollArea, one of the Labels was positioned through the bottom and it was cut in half, when scrolled the cut remained.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sidenote on conventions

First, a sidenote on [conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): class names should start with an uppercase letter, function and method names should be all lowercase.
They are conventions, so you are free to not follow them, but following the conventions will make your code more readable to people used to them.

#### The quick fix

The error is in the `ScrollArea.Make()` method. Look carefully at these two lines:

```
self._sub_surface = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size,pygame.SRCALPHA)
self._scroll_surf = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)
```

`self._sub_surface` is the surface of the window of the scroll area. `self._scroll_surf` is the scrolling surface. The latter should be higher, but you set them to the same size (same width is fine, same height not).
Obviously when you loop over your component list to blit the Label, the ones which are outside `self._sub_surface` are also outside `self._scroll_surf` and hence are not blit at all. You should make `self._scroll_surf` higher. Try for example:

```
self._scroll_surf = pygame.Surface((self.rect.width, self.rect.height*10)
```

Better would be to estimate the proper height to contains all your labels, which should be `scroll_height`, but you calculate it later in the method, so you should figure how to do properly this part.

#### A general advice

In general, I think you have a design problem here:

```
for i in range(20):
    scroll_components.append(Label(screen,(0,0),str(i),font_label,grey))
scroll_area = ScrollArea(screen, pygame.Rect(screen_width/2,3*screen_height/16 + 120,300,200),grey,scroll_components)
```

When you create each label, you pass the `screen` as the reference surface where the `Draw` method blits.
But these labels should be blitted on the `scroll_surf` of your `ScrollArea`. But you cannot do it because you have not instantiated yet the `ScrollArea`, and you cannot instantiate before the scroll area because you require the Labels to be passed as an argument.

And in fact in the `ScrollArea.Make()` method you overwrite each label `surface` attribute with the `_scroll_surf` Surface.

I think would be better to pass to `ScrollArea` a list of strings, and let the `ScrollArea.__init__()` method to create the labels.
It will look less patched and more coherent.

Comment: Thank you, I calculated the required size then created `_scroll_surf` with the correct size, then after that drew all of the components; this fixed the issue.

Comment: in response to the design problem, I want to be able to put other components within the `ScrollArea` (e.g. a picture); this means I cannot just give it a text input. I could try to remove the patchyness by creating a different method for creating components which doesn't require surface or positional values.

Comment: Then I would let the user create a surface with the scrolled content and pass it to `ScrollArea`. Maximum freedom, the user can pass whatever he wants.